# Обработчик нескольких кнопок Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xml, button, xamarin

Допустим имеется 2 кнопки:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonRock"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonScissors"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1" />
```

В метод ImageButtonlick() нужно сделать нажатие на любую из этих двух кнопок(C#):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        ButtonClick();
        ImageButtonClick();
    }

    private void ButtonClick()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetTitle(" ").SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Combination);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
            alert.Show();
        };
    }

    private void ImageButtonClick()
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextView1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        logic = new Logic();
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        ButtonClick();
        ImageButtonRockClick();
        ImageButtonScissorsClick();
        ImageButtonPaperClick();
        ImageButtonLizardClick();
        ImageButtonSpockClick();

        logic.Start();
        logic.Transf(builder);
        ViewHash();
    }



private void ImageButtonRockClick()
    {
        Imagebutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ImageButtonRock);
        Imagebutton.Click += delegate
        {
            logic.Start();
        };

    }

    private void ImageButtonScissorsClick()
    {
        Imagebutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ImageButtonScissors);
        Imagebutton.Click += delegate
        {
            logic.Start();
        };
    }

    private void ImageButtonPaperClick()
    {
        Imagebutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ImageButtonPaper);
        Imagebutton.Click += delegate
        {
            logic.Start();
        };
    }

    private void ImageButtonLizardClick()
    {
        Imagebutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ImageButtonLizard);
        Imagebutton.Click += delegate
        {
            logic.Start();
        };
    }

    private void ImageButtonSpockClick()
    {
        Imagebutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ImageButtonSpock);
        Imagebutton.Click += delegate
        {
            logic.Start();
        };
    }



<Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonRock"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonRockClick"
        android:background="@xml/round_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rock"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonScissors"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonScissorsClick"
        android:background="@xml/round_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonPaper"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonPaperClick"
        android:background="@xml/round_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonLizard"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonLizardClick"
        android:background="@xml/round_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageButtonSpock"
        android:onClick="ImageButtonSpockClick"
        android:background="@xml/round_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />
```